# Send keypressed to an app

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I'm trying to send virtual button presses to an app. I tried using `SendKeys.Send("{6}");`, but the app receives it like a string or something similar because it doesn't act. The app I want to send the key to is VisualBoy Advance. My code simply allows me to play remotely using a GUI, so when I press left on the GUI the VBA should receive the keystroke.

A part of the code:

```
case "derecha":
    SendKeys.SendWait("{4}");
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{` and `}` characters are special escape characters. I don't think `6` is an escape value. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx for the known escapes. For example, `SendKeys.SendWait("{Right}");` would send a right arrow key.

However,

*Many* games and emulators will be using low level keyboard hooks to read the keyboard state. It's quite rare to find games that use the Windows events model for keyboard reading. `SendKeys` only sends to the Windows messaging system. You may need a more low-level way of sending events.

If the target app is using DirectInput, you might be able to use the `SendInput` function from `user32.dll`:

- Docs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
- Example - http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/mmo/warhammer-online/186390-sendinput-example-c.html

There is also the Interception library, but I've never used it myself:

- http://oblita.com/interception.html

Comment: Yup! i'm currently changed my code to:                 
                    case "derecha":
                    keybd_event(0x33, 0, 0x0001, 0);
                    keybd_event(0x33, 0, 0x0002, 0);
                    break;
But still doesnt work, maybe a bit of time between pressing and up the button?

Comment: Yes, I'd put a `Thread.Sleep(34)` in there -- which should be about 2 frames worth of key-down.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, I have completed my code, the final script of the keypresses is this:                     keybd_event(0x35, 0, 0, 0);
                    Thread.Sleep(15);
                    keybd_event(0x35, 0, 0x0002, 0);

It works well and interact with any program :D